# Find a matrix A such that T(x) = Ax given two linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T([a,-b])=[−x,y]$ and $T([a,b])=[x,y]$. Find a matrix $A$ such that $T(x)=Ax$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Hint : Find out what $T(0,1)$ and $T(1,0)$ is from linearity of $T$ and the given information.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can turn this into a system of equations. Suppose you had the required matrix 
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Then

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$
and 
$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 4
\end{bmatrix}
$

Multiply this out and set each component equal to eachother to get a system of 4 variables and 4 equations. Solve it then substitute back in $a,b,c,d$ to the matrix for the answer.

Comment: and this matrix will be A?

Comment: I did call it A in my answer. Was there something unclear about it?

Comment: oops sorry, I just skimmed over it, didn't see it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Write $e_1$ and $e_2$ in terms of $v_1=e_1-e_2$ and $v_2=e_1+2e_2$. Then use that $Tv_1=-v_1$ and $Tv_2=2v_2$.